# Аналог IntlChar::charAge из PHP в C#

Tags: c#, unicode, icu

В PHP есть функция [IntlChar::charAge](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/intlchar.charage.php) которая для codepoint возвращает версию юникода в которой был принят символ с этим codepoint.

Как/где получить аналог этой функции в C# ?